# Is it possible to generate a Linux Shared Object (.so) file using .NET Core? (or using .NET 5)

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core, .net-5

I know how to build and run a self-contained native Linux executable using the dotnet CLI,
but the question here is about creating a **native Linux library** (typically a shared object .so) which
could then be **called from another application** which won't be a .NET Core application (it could be a Java application for instance).

Is this possible to create such library with .NET Core? Or with the newly released .NET 5?

Comment: have you found [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/3854) yet? is one of the suggested solutions applicable to your use case?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but [this repository](https://github.com/AaronRobinsonMSFT/DNNE) is probably doing what you have in mind.
It is also from MS, so it may become a supported feature in the future.